# Trying to target class and nth-child using standard JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to rewrite the following jQuery method using standard JavaScript because of requirement that a third-party plugin is requiring but I'm not finding a way to do it thus far.

```
var productprice = $(".product-listing:nth-child(2)").html();
```

I've tried this, but no luck

```
var productprice = document.getElementsByClassName("product-listing")[1].innterText;
```

Comment: `innerText`, not `innter`?

Comment: what was the actual result?

Comment: intertext?what is that?innerHTML maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using your solution wrong. There is a typo in "innerText" It should be like this.

```
var productprice = document.getElementsByClassName("product-listing")[1].innerText;
```

Alternate: can also use innerHtml instead of innerText.

```
var productprice = document.getElementsByClassName("product-listing")[1].innerHtml;
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo - I'm still getting a response of "undefined" though.

Comment: Got it working just had to put a 0 in front of the selector.
      var productprice = document.getElementsByClassName("product-listing")[01].innerHTML;